# Weak password of 6 characters or more with at least 1 digit

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create regular expression for password that has length of atleast 6 characters and contains at least 1 digit in it. This is the expression I came up with:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^?=\d.{6,}$");
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anybody tell me why?

I guess it says between beginning and ending, it performs look ahead to see if any digit appears in password. It appears, then says anything can repeat {6,} says minimum 6 characters. But this doesn't seem to work. Can anybody correct me on this?

**Update:** On request of Albin Sunnanbo I have changed title from strong password to weak.

Comment: Edited the title to "6 characters" - I think that is what you meant.

Comment: I wouldn't call `qwert1` a strong password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your noncapturing group is missing parenthesis. Try this:

```
^(?=.*\d).{6,}$
```

Small test to verify some basic functionality:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckAtLeastNotSuperWeakPassword()
    {
        var r = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\d).{6,}$");
        Action<string, bool> a = (s, b) =>
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(b, r.IsMatch(s), s);
        };
        a("", false);
        a("a", false);
        a("abcdef", false);
        a("abcdefg", false);
        a("1", false);
        a("abc1e", false);
        a("abc1ef", true);
        a("1bcaef", true);
        a("cbcae1", true);
        a("cbcae1wqd32", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Regular expressions are not very good at requirements like "contains at least x at any position".

Try this:

```
bool result = (password.Length >= 6) && password.Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: Actually I am using Asp.Net regular expression validator. It's cant take in code. It would be much better if you describe the above logic in terms of regular expression. I have posted it using Regex because I am trying sample in console application. However my real use is in Asp.Net.

Answer (score 2):

[Password Validation via RegEx](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/) has a decent discussion about the topic.

You can use:

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*.{6,})\w*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a problem for regular expressions. If you have a set of criteria for a password string, just write code to check for those.

You'll end up with a much more expresive, easier to maintain solution in the long run.

pseudocode-ish

```
 If pass <> confirmPass Then
        FailPasswordCheck("Password and confirmation did not match.")
        Return False
    End If
    If pass.Length < 7 Then
        FailPasswordCheck("Password must be at least 7 characters long.")
        Return False
    End If

    If Not ContaintsNumericChar(pass) Then
        FailPasswordCheck("Password must have at least 1 number.")
        Return False
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice simple one:

```
(?=.*/d).{6}
```

Explained

```
(?=.*/d)       #a look around for a digit preceded by any number of chars.
.{6}           #6 chars
```

---

***Note:*** *I don't include the start (`^`), end of string (`$`), or more than 6 chars (`{6,}`) because they aren't strictly necessary for the original question.*